# Adding Index to Match formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have the formula below working correctly, it is returning the max value in column G when the other conditions apply (valumes in B and F). However now I know what the Max number I want to return the value in Column A.

I have no idea where to begin, I can't find a way to add in the index, which I assume I need. Thanks for any help you can offer.

{=MAX(IF(PeerSummary!E$2:E$22089=B460,IF(PeerSummary!F$2:F$22089=C460,PeerSummary!G$2:G$22089)))}

Answer (score 0):

The max array function delivers the max number. You plug that number into an Index/Match combo

Index(A:A,Match((your match formula),G:G,0))

If there is more than one match, only the first one will be returned.

The formula in cell H1 is this, entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(IF(PeerSummary!E$2:E$22089=B1,IF(PeerSummary!F$2:F$22089=C1,PeerSummary!G$2:G$22089))),G:G,0))
```

I changed some of the references to row 1 for the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: What does that final G:G do?  Also I changed the A:A to reference the tab named PeerSummary, since that is the data base I am referencing and want to pull the name from column A (sorry if I wasn't clear in my question).

Comment: Also, thank you for including the screenshot, but unfortunately they are blocked on the network I am on.

Comment: The last G:G is the column where the Match function looks for a match to the value of the Max function. Match(what,where,0). The "what" is your Max function. The "Where" is G:G. That will return a number. This number is then fed to Index(A:A, number)